# Can I perform a regex search on Redis values?

Tags: java, regex, kotlin, redis, full-text-search

I tried using RedisSearch but there you can perform a fuzzy search, but I need to perform a regex search like:

```
key: "12345"
value: { name: "Maruti"}
```

searching "aru" will give the result "Mumbai", basically the regex formed is `*aru*`. Can anyone help me out how can I achieve it using Redis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but I do not recommend it - performance will be greatly impacted.

If you must, however, you can use [RedisGears](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears) for ad-hoc regex queries like so:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET mykey name Maruti
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> HSET anotherkey name Moana
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> RG.PYEXECUTE "import re\np = re.compile('.*aru.*')\nGearsBuilder().filter(lambda x: p.match(x['value']['name'])).map(lambda x: x['key']).run()"
1) 1) "mykey"
2) (empty array)
```

Here's the Python code for readability:

```py
import re
p = re.compile('.*aru.*')
GearsBuilder() \
    .filter(lambda x: p.match(x['value']['name'])) \
    .map(lambda x: x['key']) \
    .run()
```